# DNS issue on Debian 10

Tags: linux, debian, dns, systemd

I'm currently facing an issue on my Debian server where:

- the `ping` command (and all my applications) is unable to resolve hostnames

but

- I can successfully resolve hostnames using the `systemd-resolve` command.

Here's the output of `systemd-resolve`:

```bash
my_server@my_user:~$ systemd-resolve google.com
google.com: 216.58.206.46                      -- link: eth0

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 42.6ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

However, when I try to `ping` a hostname, I get the following error:

```bash
my_server@my_user:~$ ping -c 4 google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

##### What's particularly puzzling is that this problem appears after the server has been running for a few days. After a reboot, the problem disappears.

I've checked my DNS configuration, and the DNS servers in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` appear to be correctly configured. I've also cleared the DNS cache using `sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches`.

I'm unsure why there's a discrepancy between the successful DNS resolution using `systemd-resolve` and the failure with the `ping` command.

Could anyone provide insight into why this issue might be occurring and how to resolve it?

Comment: Does [this manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460886/165358) solve the problem (at least until the next reboot) ? Check also `/etc/hosts `.

Comment: hi @harrymc, it just happened so I had to reboot. When the issue will show up again in some days, I will try this.

Comment: I have quoted this in an answer. Given the high number of upvotes of this Stack Overflow answer, many people found it to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the network inconsistency on my Debian server was traced to the firewall settings, particularly the Uncomplicated Firewall (UFW), potentially interacting with fail2ban and suricata. Even after uninstalling fail2ban and suricata, the server's network ceased to function properly, persisting even after reboots.

The challenge lay in the subtlety of the issue. Although disabling ufw seemed an obvious step, it inexplicably had no immediate effect unless the server was rebooted.

The workaround that finally resolved the problem involved a sequence of actions:

1. Uninstalled fail2ban
2. Uninstalled suricata
3. Disabled ufw (`sudo ufw disable`)
4. Rebooted the server (*important*)
5. Reset ufw (`sudo ufw reset`)
6. Enabled ufw (`sudo ufw enable`)
7. Recreated the firewall rules

This sequence ensured a consistent server network state. I remain optimistic that this resolution will be enduring, but I'll update this answer should the issue resurface.

Answer (score 0):

I quote below the
[accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460886/165358)
from the Stack Overflow post
[Linux command line error message: Temporary failure in name resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687051/linux-command-line-error-message-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution/54460886#54460886).
This answer had received a very high number upvotes.

> I've faced the exactly same problem but I've fixed it with another
> approache.
>
> Using Ubuntu 18.04, first disable `systemd-resolved` service.
>
> `sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service`
>
> Stop the service
>
> `sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service`
>
> Then, remove the link to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` in
> `/etc/resolv.conf`
>
> `sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf`
>
> Add a manually created `resolv.conf` in `/etc/`
>
> `sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf`
>
> Add your prefered DNS server there
>
> `nameserver 208.67.222.222`
>
> I've tested this with success.

Comment: I think I have tried that, but I will try it again as soon as the issue raises again and I will let you know. Thank you for now.

Comment: It happened again and I have just tried that, but no luck, even temporarily. I find amazing that one of the oldest service in the history of Internet is so buggy on Linux.